# setState with nested JSON

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to RN and am trying to figure out how to use setState with nested JSON.

My object is in the following format:

```
{
  "data": {
    "count": 1,
    "current": [
      {
        "Id":"284"
      },
      {
        "Id":"285"
      },
      {
        "Id":"286"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have set the state as follow:

```
state = { notices: [data] };
```

I need to update the count value and set state:

```
this.state.notices[0].data.count = newcount
```

I am trying to do it wth `this.setState` but I can't figure out how to set it for nested JSON.

Comment: you cant do that, you have to change whole data then set that modified data into state

Comment: Sounds like a job for something like https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper or a state machine like Redux or MobX.

Comment: What if my state is state = {notices:[data]}. and I sent  count. That is this.state.count = 1. Not I need to updated the this.state.count to newcount. Can I do that with setState?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as following:

```
updateNotices = (newcount) => {
  const { notices } = this.state;
  const newNotices = [... notices];
  newNotices[0].data.count = newcount;
  this.setState({ notices: newNotices });
}
```

Then, you can call `updateNotices(1)`.

Comment: are you sure you did this inside component? this.setState() function is only available to call inside component.

Comment: got it thanks! I put the code in the wrong place. Also one more question, how do I rerender screne after the update

Comment: after updating state variable, the component is relevant to updated state is automatically updated.

Comment: spread(...) operator works only on one level nested copy of the copy. If there is more than one, this fails.